# clicking outside button is working in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4

I push one view controller from one controller.But i did not press back button in navigation bar.when i click the area which is below, back button
is working,poping viewcontroller is happening? how can i overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a bug, it's by design. Apple make the hit area of the back button bigger than the button itself so it's easier to tap.

I suggest changing your design so there are no buttons directly underneath the back button (Apple never put buttons there in their own apps).